# Android Pattern matching (not matching)

Tags: android, regex, spannablestring

I am trying to match "\b\w+:" inside the string "Search\nPrefix with tag: app: or text:"

The code looks like:

```js
String s = "Search\nPrefix with tag: app: or text:";
SpannableString str = SpannableString.valueOf(s);
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+:");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(str);

while(m.find()) {
   // do stuff
}
```

I followed the code with the debugger, in Eclipse, and the while loop is never entered, meaning m.find() returns false.
I tried to change the regex to the straightforward

```js
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("app:");
```

It should work, right?, it is the same explicit text from the string. But still there is no match.
I suspect that the matcher stops matching when it reaches the newline in the string. And somehow there must be a flag or something to tell the matcher to scan the whole string.

Comment: Should work the way it is. Maybe it does not like `SpannableString`, try `Matcher m = regex.matcher(s);`

Comment: Just to make sure, I tried the string and it is the same. I need though the spannable, because I want to color the matches and  I need m.start() & m.end() for each m.find() to do it.

Comment: My mistake, again. I simplified the code to show it here, but in practice the while condition was m.find() && --count>0, and count was the culprit. The regex was OK.   The conclusion is: "Go to sleep if you are too tired to work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, again.
I simplified the code to show it here, but in practice the while condition was

```js
while(m.find() && --count>0)
```

, and **count** was the culprit. The regex was OK. 
The conclusion is: "Go to sleep if you are too tired to work"

Comment: heh. You shouldn't simplify code when posting. It's very common that these kinds of mistakes are the underlying problem :p

Comment: @Keyser, You are right that these kind of mistakes are common when simplifying the code. On the other hand when you have a very long code with complicated functions and calls, the fear is that potentially people will not have the time and patience to filter the unrelated code by themselves and will not bother to try to understand the question. Specially when you target a very simple aspect of your code. I think simplifying is OK, you just have to do it right; when you don't it happens what happened to me here.